# Instance of resource in Java rest api

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restful-url

I have a java rest api. What I want to know is this:

Say one specific client (e.g. person named X is using computer Y) makes three calls to the same uri. (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/firstname/kasav/lastname/bere). Further, say the resource has a non-static counter.

```
class ResourceA{
     int count = 0;

     @Get
     public Response service(){
        count++;
        //return count below
     }
}
```

Now does the caller get the same response for all three calls:

```
1
```

Or does the caller get `1` for the first call, then `2` for the second call, then `3` for the third call.

For some of you this may be obvious, but not to me. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using something that follows JAX-RS spec correctly.

> **3.1.1 Lifecycle and Environment**
>
> By default a new resource class instance is created for each request to that resource. First the
> constructor (see section 3.1.2) is called, then any requested
> dependencies are injected (see section 3.2), then the appropriate
> method (see section 3.3) is invoked and finally the object is made
> available for garbage collection. An implementation MAY offer other
> resource class lifecycles, mechanisms for specifying these are outside
> the scope of this specification. E.g. an implementation based on an
> inversion-of-control framework may support all of the lifecycle
> options provided by that framework.

As such the answer to your question is all callers will receive `1` as the class is initiated for each request.

See [JSR-311](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) for the JAX-RS spec.

Comment: I did some research trying to confirm your answer and I could not. You are basically saying that one object is created for each call. What if I have one million users? That seems inefficient.

Comment: What if the resource class has no constructor as in my example. Does each user still see `0`?

Comment: I can only speak to the spec. You've left out the container you are running and much more info.

Answer (score 1):

By default JAX RS resources are request scoped, means it create new instances for each request.

To process the multiple requests with the same instance of the resource you can mark the resource (class ResourceA in this case) with the annotation @Singleton.
Marking as Singleton will make the output of the ResourceA class as 1 for first request, 2 for second request and so on.